# Why does iRobot not sell the Create in Europe?

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, irobot-create

I'm trying to find a good beginners platform to use ROS with, and I came across the iRobot Create. To my surprise, they do not sell in Europe. Why is that?

Comment: I find this question rather vague and off-topic. I'd say it has more to do with sales and business than with robotics.
Regards

Comment: This question can only be answered by someone familiar with iRobot's sales policy etc. Also, a simple google search reveals information on how to get an iCreate in europe.

Comment: @DamjanDakic How is this off-topic and vague? The questions is quite specific and its about robots. And Josh If it is that simple, why don't you just link me to the site? I've done my searching, and could not find anything adequate.

Comment: @BananaCode As I pointed out, your question does involve robots but is not a robotics question and has more to do with business and sales. You could very well post a question asking who directed Terminator and say that it's a question about robots.
As for why I think its vague is that you are asking for the reason a company made a sales decision which could most likely be answered in several pages of laws, business strategy and whatnot. Questions on stack-exchange should be such that could be fully answered in one post.
Regards

Comment: @Josh I'm still waiting for that simple google search you were telling me about.
DamjanDakic, as you could see from the answer below, a simple sentence sufficed to answer my question. In addition, your comparison was rather useless. I expect better logic from a software engineer.

Comment: Easy @BananaCode, the problem is not a robotics problem that requires archiving, and is thus not appropriate for stackexchange.  This is akin to asking how to buy a dell laptop on stackoverflow. However, I'm glad you got an answer to your question that was satisfactory. Happy hacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the Create was not sold in Europe because it is not RoHS compliant.

However, every Roomba can be hacked.  You can communicate with the robot with the "Open Interface" or sometimes called the "Serial Control Interface".  There is lots of information about this on the web.  See here for example: http://www.irobot.com/filelibrary/pdfs/hrd/create/Create%20Open%20Interface_v2.pdf

Note that you will need to either make or buy a cable to connect to the 7 pin mini-DIN port on the robot.  Every Roomba has this.  Sometimes it is under the faceplate though.

Most libraries you can find online communicate with the Roomba outlined above and do not use the "Command Module" that was unique to the Create.

Comment: I will also note that the new [Create 2](http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2.aspx) is based on iRobot's newer 600 series platform, is RoHS compliant, and therefore will be sold in Europe.